# Trigger Jenkins build on GitHub submit

Tags: github, jenkins, build, push, jobs

I have a Pipeline job in Jenkins that currently is running a jenkinsfile located in GitHub/Repo1/Repo2
The jenkinsfile itself builds another project (GitHub/Repo1/ProjectToBuild)

I'm trying to trigger a new run of the Jenkins job, whenever there is a submit in the ProjectToBuild.

I've tried with GitHub hook trigger for GITScm polling, but as the jenkinsfile is defined in the pipeline  this is not working. Giving the GitHub/Repo1 URL in the Definition is not an option.

Do you have any ideas?